# Pass Javascript Variable to HTML href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code and want to pass Javascript variable (var_x) to the HTML href path inoder to be like this `javascript:displaylightbox('./page1.php?name=var_x',{})`

```
<a href="javascript:displaylightbox('./page1.php?name=',{})" target="_self" onclick="jsfunction();return false;"><img src="i/i.png" id="Image1" alt="" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a></div>

<script>
function jsfunction()
{
var var_x = 10;
//some other code
};
</script>
```

it should open in a lightbox window and redirect to this page1.php?name=10 as 10 is the value of var_x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you call `displaylightbox` inside `jsfunction` as you are calling it `onclick`

like this

```
function jsfunction() {
    var var_x = 10;
    displaylightbox('./page1.php?name=' + var_x, {});
};
```

Comment: ok that's worked fine but didn't work like what I want so how I can embedded the var_x in the HTML href??